# Youtube data apiで１つのGoogleアカウントで複数のチャンネルを持ってる場合のリクエスト方法

Tags: android, java, youtube-data-api

Youtube data api v3をJava用のクライアントをつかって使用しています。

```
YouTube.Channels.List channelRequest = youTube.channels().list("id, snippet, contentDetails");
channelRequest.setMine(true);
channelRequest.setMaxResults(10L);
channelRequest.setFields("items(id,snippet/title)");
channelRequest.setOauthToken(mToken);
ChannelListResponse channels = channelRequest.execute();
List<Channel> listOfChannels = channels.getItems();
```

このようにして認証されたユーザーのチャンネルIDをリクエストしているのですが、ユーザーが複数のチャンネルを所持していても1つのレスポンスし返ってきません。
１アカウントで複数のチャンネルを所持している場合はどのようにリクエストすればいいのでしょう。

Answer (score 1):

アカウント（token）とチャンネルは1対1の関係になっているので、1つのtokenでは1つのチャンネルしか返ってきません。
ユーザが複数のチャンネルを持っている時、2つ目以降のチャンネルに対しては仮想的なアカウントが生成されて紐付けられています。
oAuth認証するときに、チャンネルを複数持っているユーザであれば「チャンネルセレクト」の画面が出て、選択されたチャンネルによって別のtokenが返ってきます。

Answer (score -1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515743/youtube-api-channel-selector
現在androidにビルドインされているOAuth2認証方法だとchannelは選べない仕様っぽいです。webviewで実装していきます。